# Identifying td tr with css select

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble identifying td and ts with css selectors. I'd like to move some elements around the page so gave them a div class. Howver using this in css doesn't seem to work.

What is the selector here please, as I can't understand if td, tr is acting as a label and in what sense?

Html:

```
<div class="ye">
  <td>Your Email
  </td>
</div>
<div class="ye1">.
  <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
</div>
</tr>
<tr>
  <div class="un">
    <td>Username:</td>.
  </div>
  <div class="un1">
    <td><input type="text" name="username" />.
    </td>
  </div>
</tr>
<tr>
  <div class="pw">
    <td>
      <div align="right">Password:</div>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
    </d iv>
</tr>
<tr>
  <div class="
     sub">
    </td>
  </div>
  <div class="sub1">
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </div>
  </tr "> 
     </table></form></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `td` inside a `div` is a big no no. Best practise it to keep the `tr > td` hirerarchy as is.

You can restructure it to have all your `div` inside td. Please check the code below.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="ye">
          Your Email
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="ye1">
          <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, to use css,

```
table tbody .ye {
   ...
}

table tbody .ye1 input {
   ...
}
```